# Monitoring application health and what users do with javascript

Tags: java, javascript, stability

I am a Java developer doing my first steps with JavaScript.

In the next couple of months my Javascript code is going to be pushed to production and had a question about code and application monitoring.

With java (or any major programming language for that matter) there are tools to monitor the application health - logs, exceptions, asserts.. Which once a bug is being opened, provides me more information about the server state.

- Or scanning the logs I can tell if there were any issues with the applications.

How do I know what my customers are doing with the UI? How do I send exceptions or logs to my client? Should I do it or it is unnecessary overhead?

What are there coding practices or tools that I can achieve it on the JavasScript side? links to good articles/tutorials around this topic will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you care about logging JS errors or back-end errors or both?

Answer (score 1):

Most modern browsers have a console available with `ctrl-shift-j` or `ctrl-shift-k` (at least on linux), though the grandaddy of such consoles is Firebug, an extension for firefox (et al, but primarily firefox:
http://getfirebug.com/. Especially important to debugging is the use of `console.log` to write to these consoles for figuring out how far you've gone in the script.

EDIT: missed the bit about server things. I would suggest avoiding nodeJS until you're a bit further in with normal JS.

Lastly, use libraries after you need them if you want a deep understanding of the language